# Input and Select Issue with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Good day, I have an issue and I have been trying to find a way out all day, with no luck.

The snap shot below is a `form` in which I want to enable the button when the select field changes and it is not empty and the input field is also not empty.

Below is what I've tried.
the currently enables the button when I return back to the input box.

[image]

```js
skillButton = function() {
  var skill = $.trim($("#skillauto").val());
  //$('select[name=selector]').val()
  var level = $("#level :selected").val()
    //if((skill !== '') && (level !== '')) && (level !== '')
  if ((skill !== '') && (level !== '')) {
    //alert(level);
    $('form.js-form-skills')
      .find('button#putskill')
      .prop('disabled', false);
  } else {

    $('button#putskill').prop("disabled", true);

  };
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden" id="skills">
  <div class="form-row form-wrapper cf">

    <div class="control is-horizontal">
      <div class="control is-grouped">
        <p class="control is-expanded">
          <!-- <span class="js-awesomplete"> -->
          <input maxlength="20" id="skillauto" name="skill" placeholder="Add Skill" class="capitalize input is-fullwidth" value="" type="text">
          <!-- </span> -->
        </p>
        <p class="control is-expanded">
          <span class="select is-fullwidth">
            <select id="level" name="level">
    <option value="" class="hidden">Experience Level</option>
    <?php if($skillevels):
      foreach($skillevels AS $level):?>
            <option value="<?=$level->level_id?>"><?=$level->level_name?></option>
      <?php endforeach;
      endif;?>
       </select>
   </span>
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="control">
      <input type="hidden" name="skproceed" value="yea">
      <button class="button is-primary" id="putskill"><span>Submit</span>
      </button>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue? Please provide the minimum amount of code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: And show us how select is implemented. How could it be empty?

Comment: have just updated my question.

Comment: And how about html code? Did you set button on disabled like this `<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>`?

Comment: i tried that, did not work

Comment: Can you post your html snippet also?

Comment: just did that now @Brijesh Vishwakarma

Comment: FYI, you can use `$("level").val()`, you don't need `:selected`

Comment: with or without it, it make no difference, just left it there for no reason.@Barmar

Comment: I never said it would make a difference, it's not related to the problem. That's why it's just a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `disabled` in the button's attributes in the original HTML, so it starts out disabled. Then you can run your function when the select or input is changed with:

```
$("#level").change(skillButton);
$("#skillauto").on("input", skillButton);
```

Comment: Oh my, this just save my day, thanks man i so much appreciate. @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

First You need to keep this function on change of select box
Like this

```
$('#level').change(function() {
    var skill = $("#skillauto").val(),
      level = $("#level:selected").val()
      //if((skill !== '') && (level !== '')) && (level !== '')
    if ((skill !== '') && (level !== '')) {
      //alert(level);
      $('button#putskill').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {

      $('button#putskill').prop("disabled", true);

    };
  });
```

Second there is no element as $('form.js-form-skills') as you wrote in if statement of function.

Comment: its there, just did not share that aspect, thanks for the fix

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is working code, you have to write something inside input, then button get enable.

```js
function onChange() {
  console.log('input change')
  var skill = $.trim($("#skillauto").val());
  //$('select[name=selector]').val()
  var level = $("#level :selected").val()
    //if((skill !== '') && (level !== '')) && (level !== '')
  if ((skill !== '') && (level !== '')) {
    //alert(level);
      $('button#putskill')
      .prop('disabled', false);
  } else {

    $('button#putskill').prop("disabled", true);
  };
}

$('#skillauto').change(onChange);
$('#level').change(onChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden" id="skills">
  <div class="form-row form-wrapper cf">

    <div class="control is-horizontal">
      <div class="control is-grouped">
        <p class="control is-expanded">
          <!-- <span class="js-awesomplete"> -->
          <input maxlength="20" id="skillauto" name="skill" placeholder="Add Skill" class="capitalize input is-fullwidth" value="" type="text">
          <!-- </span> -->
        </p>
        <p class="control is-expanded">
          <span class="select is-fullwidth">
            <select id="level" name="level">
    <option value="" class="hidden">Experience Level</option>
    <?php if($skillevels):
      foreach($skillevels AS $level):?>
            <option value="<?=$level->level_id?>"><?=$level->level_name?></option>
      <?php endforeach;
      endif;?>
       </select>
  </span>
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="control">
      <input type="hidden" name="skproceed" value="yea">
      <button disabled class="button is-primary" id="putskill"><span>Submit</span>
      </button>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```